# Non-static method 'getSharedPreferences (java.lang.String, int)' cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-view, android-button

I have an app, and I am trying to limit the number of button clicks to five, and then once the user has pressed this button five times it should disable.

However I am getting the above error and I am not sure why.

Any ideas ?

```
          buttonadd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener () {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity3.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            int clicks = 0;
            clicks++;

            if (clicks >= 5){
                buttonadd.setEnabled(false);
            }

            SharedPreferences prefs = Context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt("clicks", clicks);
            editor.apply();

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are wrongly trying to use the *virtual* method `getSharedPreferences()` in a *static* way, that's why its giving that compile-time error.

If that code is in an `Activity`, replace

```
Context.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with

```
getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

If it is in a `Fragment`, use

```
getActivity().getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**EDIT:**

use

```
if (clicks >= 5){
    buttonadd.setEnabled(false);
    buttonadd.setClickable(false);
    buttonadd.setFocusable(false);
    buttonadd.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
}
```

and make `clicks` a class member, i.e. declare it as

```
private int clicks;
```

in the `Activity`.

**EDIT 2:**

I think I have understood the mistake you are making. In your code, replace

```
int clicks = 0;
```

with

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int clicks = prefs.getInt("clicks", 0);
```

Try this. This should do it.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed that and its worked. However when I've tested it out, its still letting me click the button more than 5 times...

Comment: about to now, I will let you know.

Comment: It is still allowing more than 5 clicks of the button.

Comment: `clicks` is always 1 because after each click you create a new `clicks` set to 0 then increment it to 1.  If you move the clicks variable to the class it will work.  There's no need to store it.  You need to go back and review your understanding of variable scope and extant.

Comment: @pzulw: while you are right, I think what he wants is that the button should be clickable 5 times PERIOD, that's why he's using a `SharedPreference`. I have suggested EDIT 2 for that to work correctly  :)

Comment: @Y.S. it looks like your 2nd edit is correct, but I would rewrite the entire answer to show the complete `onClick` method. OP should load the prefs value for clicks, increment clicks by one, save clicks in prefs file, then disable button if clicks is >= 5.

Comment: @ekchang: yes you're right, in the 2nd edit I merely pointed out the mistake he was making. I'll re-edit it when I get a moment ... or you can go ahead and do it, i'll approve it if its right  :)

Answer (score 2):

It means that you need an instance of a `Context` object to call the `getSharedPreferences()` method. If you're inside an `Activity`, try this:

```
this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
```

Comment: Thats worked thank you. However when I've tested it, it still lets the user press the button more than 5 times and I'm not sure why...

Comment: There is no need to call `getApplicationContext()`. Just calling `getSharedPreferences()` will do.

Comment: what if it is an Adapter class for RecyclerView? How we can implement the Sharedpreference ? Thanks on advance

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says `getSharedPreferences()` is a non-static method. When you do `Context.getSharedPreferences(...)` you are trying to call it directly from the class. Instead, you need to call it from a `Context` instance.

If your code is inside an `Activity` (as `Activity` extends `Context`) you can simply do:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsKey", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```