# What is a proper way to store key:value returned by registerForActivityResult()?

Tags: android

I am trying to catch and store the file path selected by user using `registerForActivityResult`. It returns the path, I can print the path but I am not able to store it using SharedPreferences class as it requires an app context which I cannot get using `getApplicationContext()` in static `SettingsFragment`.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {...}
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {...}

    public  class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(
                new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                new ActivityResultCallback<Uri>() {
                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("MYAPP", "File selected:" + uri.toString());
// the added code is right below. 
                        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences( BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
                        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("audio_filename", uri.toString());
                        editor.apply();
                        
                    }
                });

        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceTreeClick(Preference preference) {
            String key = preference.getKey();
            if (key.equals("audio_filename")) {
                mGetContent.launch("*/*");
                return true;
            }
            return super.onPreferenceTreeClick(preference);
        }
  }
}
```

The code I used from [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) but it seems missing integration between `SharedPreferences` and `registerForActivityResult`.

UPDATE1 (Clarification): This is a podcast player, actually I try to play audio using `MediaPlayer` class. The app has `MainActivity` and `SettingActivity`. The idea is the `SettingActivity` is to select an audio file and save its file path (`SharedPreferences`) then on the next app start (`MainActivity` retrieves last file path from `SharedPreferences`) I do not need to select it again but continue listening selected file instead.

UPDATE2: When I define SharePreferences it asks me to remove `static` from `SettingsFragment` definition. But when I run the app an error thrown:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.audiotranscriptd/com.example.audiotranscriptd.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment com.example.audiotranscriptd.SettingsActivity.SettingsFragment must be a public static class to be  properly recreated from instance state.
```

Comment: `uri.getPath())` That is no file system path. Its useless. Only uri.toString() shows you a valid content scheme. It makes no sense to save it for later use as then the use permission has gone. Further i see no key:value pair and no shared preferences. What did you try?

Comment: @blackapps, yes, you are right I got the `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/media/0/Download/033.mp3: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` exception. I have added some update to my post above to clarify what I want to do in the app. Really, I  appreciate  if you can explain how should I handle files.

Comment: Sorry, but it is as if you did not read my comment. There is still that getPath() and there is no shared preferences.

Comment: Well, now I did it in my post. But in either case path or `content://` gives me a string. How do I store it from `registerForActivityResult` into SharedPreferences internal file to let `MainActivity` to read the selected file in `onCreate` then?

Comment: Well add the code where you save that string to shared preferences. There is nothing special on saving a string. Do it directly after that Log.i() call.

Comment: corrected.Please find the UPDATE2 in the post

Comment: ???? Nothing corrected. You did not add the code i asked for. Do it here: `// Handle the returned Uri`.

Answer (score 0):

Found solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418386/non-static-method-getsharedpreferences-java-lang-string-int-cannot-be-refer) . It appears in `Fragment` the `getSharedPreferences` should be called with `getActivity()`, like this

```
sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + "_preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Works for me!